# How to keep checking array until certain condition is met

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, optimization

I have two arrays `idarray` and `array` and want to find `item_tosearch` in `idarray`. Then using the found index loop forward through `idarray` until an element is found that is not `-1`. Then use that index to retreive the value from `array`.

From what I know, if you want to keep checking you can use any sort of iteration either `for` or `while` or `foreach` in this case, I've got 2 arrays. First is for `idarray` and second is for `array`. I've managed to check what is the next data and if the data has reached the final value. I also able to get what I want which is the next data as long as the `id` wasn't `-1`.

What I've tried:

```js
var item_tosearch = 0;
var idarray = [-1, 2, -1, 4, -1]
var array = [3, 2, 1, 0, 7];
var index = array.indexOf(item_tosearch);

if (index > -1) {
  var res = array.slice(index);
}

if (res != undefined) {
  for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    if (res[i + 1] != undefined) {
      if (idarray[index + 1] == -1) {
        if (res[i + 2] != undefined) {
          console.log("Next = " + res[i + 2]);
          break;
        } else {
          console.log("Final index");
          break;
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Next = " + res[i + 1]);
        break;
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Final index");
    }
  }
} else {
  console.log('data not found');
}
```

My question is, is there any way I could've improved the method?

Any advice is apreciated.

---

Clarification:

If I have the following:

idarray = [-1, 2, -1, 4, 1];
array = [3, 2, 1, 0, 7];

What I would like to have is if I put 2 on item_tosearch as value, I'm expecting to have: 0 as the returned value since it was the next item without -1 in the id.

---

Another case, if I had:

idarray = [-1, 2, -1, -1, 1];
array = [3, 2, 1, 0, 7];

And if I put 2 on item_tosearch as value, I'm expecting to have: 7 as the returned value since it was the next item without -1 in the id.

But if idarray was = [-1, 2, -1, -1, -1] with the same 2 on item_tosearch as value. I expect "final index" to be returned. Since no more item without -1 as the id.

I've tried another iteration to fetch but doesn't seem to get what I want:

```js
var item_tosearch = 2;
var idarray = [-1, 2, -1, -1, -1]
var array = [3, 2, 1, 0, 7];
var index = array.indexOf(item_tosearch);

if (index > -1) {
  var res = array.slice(index);
}

if (res != undefined) {
  for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    if (res[i + 1] != undefined) {
      if (idarray[index + 1] == -1) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < res.length - i; j++) {
          if (res[j + 1] != undefined) { // fetch if still got data with id != -1
            console.log("Next = " + res[j + 1]); // should show next item without -1 in id
            break;
          } else {
            console.log("Final index"); // reach end of array
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Next = " + res[i + 1]); // should show next item without -1 in id
        break;
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Final index"); // reach end of array
    }
  }
} else {
  console.log('data not found');
}
```

Comment: Could you explain in words what you are trying to calculate? It seems like you want to know if some values still exist, but that should be very easy by comparing the length of `res` and `idarray`. Hence could you explain the logic better? Since we can probably code this using array methods like `.forEach()`, `.filter()`, and `.find()`, making the whole a bit more readable.

Comment: @Shilly Actually, array and idarray are based on the same level. But I was fetching id from front-end value while the array was from backend which I calculate the next item if id wasn't -1. If it was then I would fetch the next item. But as you can notice if idarray value was changed into:  [-1, 2, -1, -1, -1] and pos to 2 you would find that it's not returning the "final index" console since I need to recursively increase the + value in:  `if (res[i + 2] != undefined) {
          console.log("Next = " + res[i + 2]);` but I haven't managed to do so. I hope that was clear enough.

Comment: @Shinjo I don't think you got the point. You're telling too much details while we have no clue what you try to achieve with the current code. We could try to reverse engineer your issue, but most people don't have the time or will to do this. Let me give you a short example: I have two arrays and are trying to find out if these arrays share any elements. I currently have the following code: ... My current issue is ...

Comment: @3limin4t0r I'm sorry m_m I've added examples of what to expect when having certain values. And another attempt to iterate it.

Comment: @Shinjo That's already a lot better. 

Comment: Are the `idarray` and `array` always the same size?

Comment: @Shinjo I've added the intent of the code to the question. Can you check if this matches your requirements?

Comment: @3limin4t0r Yes they are always the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question good enough you're looking for something like this. Even if this isn't exactly the solution you want you might be able to get some inspiration from it.

- This solution starts by finding the index of the element to search in `idarray`. If it can't be found return `undefined`.
- Next start looping from 1 index higher until the end of the `idarray`. If an element is found that is not `-1` return the element on the current index from `array`.
- If nothing is found `undefined` is returned.

```js
var idarray, array;

function giveThisABetterName(item_tosearch, idarray, array) {
  var index = idarray.indexOf(item_tosearch);
  if (index === -1) return; // data not found

  for (index += 1; index < idarray.length; ++index) {
    if (idarray[index] !== -1) return array[index];
  }
  
  // reach end of array
}

idarray = [-1, 2, -1, 4, 1];
array   = [ 3, 2,  1, 0, 7];
console.log(giveThisABetterName(2, idarray, array));

idarray = [-1, 2, -1, -1, 1];
array   = [ 3, 2,  1,  0, 7];
console.log(giveThisABetterName(2, idarray, array));

idarray = [-1, 2, -1, -1, 1];
array   = [ 3, 2,  1,  0, 7];
console.log(giveThisABetterName(9, idarray, array));
```

Comment: If the length of both arrays can vary hugely you might want to change `index < idarray.length` into `index < idarray.length && index < array.length` since there is no point in finding an index that will return `undefined` anyway because it exceeds the length of `array`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yeah, I was able to get what I want after optimize your function a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/91o0ztsw/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I kind of understand the logic, but I'm not sure.
Is the question: `I want to check if any of the ids following the id corresponding with my value, is not -1` ?

Hope I understood the logic correctly.

If you have no use for reusable functions, or don't care about structure, you can write this very short as well:

```js
var pos = 0;
var idarray = [ -1, 2, -1, 4, -1 ];
var array = [ 3, 2, 1, 0, 7 ];

var get_result = ( array, idarray, pos, ex ) => {
  const offset = array.indexOf( pos ) + 1;
  return idarray
    .slice( offset )
    .reduce(( result, id, index ) => {
      if ( result === "final index" && id !== -1 ) result = array[ index + offset ];
      return result;
    }, "final index" );
};

// example 1:
const ex1_search_value = 0; // pos
const ex1_ids = [ -1, 2, -1, 4, -1 ]; // idarray
const ex1_values = [3, 2, 1, 0, 7]; // array
// expect "final index", since our range will only contain the last id, which is -1
const result1 = get_result( ex1_values, ex1_ids, ex1_search_value );
console.log( `expect final index, ${ result1 }` );

// example2:
const ex2_search_value = 2;
const ex2_ids = [ -1, 2, -1, -1, -1 ];
const ex2_values = [3, 2, 1, 0, 7];
// expect "final index", since our range is the last two items, both with id -1
const result2 = get_result( ex2_values, ex2_ids, ex2_search_value );
console.log( `expect final index, ${ result2 }` );

// example3:
const ex3_search_value = 2;
const ex3_ids =    [ -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, -1,  2, -1, -1 ];
const ex3_values = [  3, 2,  1,  0,  7,  4,  9, 14, 74, 8, 45, 14, 17, 84 ];
// expect { id: 3, value: 8 }
const result3 = get_result( ex3_values, ex3_ids, ex3_search_value );
console.log( `expect 8, ${ result3 }` );

// example4:
const ex4_search_value = 2;
const ex4_ids =    [-1, 2, -1, 4, 1];
const ex4_values = [ 3, 2,  1, 0, 7];
// expect { id: 4, value: 0 }
const result4 = get_result( ex4_values, ex4_ids, ex4_search_value );
console.log( `expect 0, ${ result4 }` );

// example5:
const ex5_search_value = 2;
const ex5_ids =    [-1, 2, -1, -1, 1];
const ex5_values = [ 3, 2,  1,  0, 7];
// expect { id: 1, value: 7 }
const result5 = get_result( ex5_values, ex5_ids, ex5_search_value );
console.log( `expect 7, ${ result5 }` );

// example6:
const ex6_search_value = 2;
const ex6_ids =    [-1, 2, -1, -1, -1];
const ex6_values = [ 3, 2,  1,  0,  7];
// expect "final index"
const result6 = get_result( ex6_values, ex6_ids, ex6_search_value );
console.log( `expect final index, ${ result6 }` );
```

My other approach here is to merge the arrays into one array containing objects, so that we do not have to check for undefined values, while still being able to use array methods instead of plain loops. This would help if you have to use the id/value combinations alot in the code past this point. The functions are just there to make everything reusable.

```js
// Create an object from the id and value combinations.
const create_collection = ( ids, values ) => {
  return ids.map(( id, index ) => ({
    id,
    value: values[ index ]
  }));
};

const has_valid_descendants = ( collection, search_value ) => {
  // Find the index of the first item that has our requested value.
  const search_index = collection.findIndex( item => item.value === search_value );
  // Slice the relevant part from the collection.
  // Since we will only look at records past the item ahving the search_value, we mights well only slice the relevant parts.
  const collection_in_range = collection.slice( search_index + 1 );
  // Find the first item in range has an id that is not -1.
  return collection_in_range.find( item => item.id !== -1 ) || 'final index';
};


// example 1:
const ex1_search_value = 0; // pos
const ex1_ids = [ -1, 2, -1, 4, -1 ]; // idarray
const ex1_values = [3, 2, 1, 0, 7]; // array
// Collection should be: [{ id: -1, value: 3 },{ id: 2, value: 2 },{ id: -1, value: 1 },{ id: 4, value: 0 },{ id: -1, value: 7 }];
const ex1_collection = create_collection( ex1_ids, ex1_values );
console.log( ex1_collection );
// Is there a valid next item?
// expect "final index", since our range will only contain the last id, which is -1
const ex1_result = has_valid_descendants( ex1_collection, ex1_search_value );
console.log( 'expect 1: "final index"' );
console.log( `example 1: ${ JSON.stringify( ex1_result ) }` );


// example2:
const ex2_search_value = 2;
const ex2_ids = [ -1, 2, -1, -1, -1 ];
const ex2_values = [3, 2, 1, 0, 7];
// expect "final index", since our range is the last two items, both with id -1
const ex2_result = has_valid_descendants(
  create_collection( ex2_ids, ex2_values ),
  ex2_search_value
);
console.log( 'expect 2: "final index"' );
console.log( `example 2: ${ JSON.stringify( ex2_result ) }` );


// example3:
// We add a bunch of other values and ids.
// This proves it will work with longer arrays as well
// and that the result is the first item without the id -1
const ex3_search_value = 2;
const ex3_ids =    [ -1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 3, -1,  2, -1, -1 ];
const ex3_values = [  3, 2,  1,  0,  7,  4,  9, 14, 74, 8, 45, 14, 17, 84 ];
// expect { id: 3, value: 8 }
const ex3_result = has_valid_descendants(
  create_collection( ex3_ids, ex3_values ),
  ex3_search_value
);
console.log( 'expect 3: { id: 3, value: 8 }"' );
console.log( `example 3: ${ JSON.stringify( ex3_result ) }` );


// example4:
// Note: I've added || 'final index'; to the has_valid_descendants() function.
const ex4_search_value = 2;
const ex4_ids = [-1, 2, -1, 4, 1];
const ex4_values = [3, 2, 1, 0, 7];
// expect { id: 4, value: 0 }
const ex4_result = has_valid_descendants(
  create_collection( ex4_ids, ex4_values ),
  ex4_search_value
);
console.log( 'expect 4: { id: 4, value: 0 }' );
console.log( `example 4: ${ JSON.stringify( ex4_result ) }` );


// example5:
// Note: I've added || 'final index'; to the has_valid_descendants() function.
const ex5_search_value = 2;
const ex5_ids = [-1, 2, -1, -1, 1];
const ex5_values = [3, 2, 1, 0, 7];
// expect { id: 1, value: 7 }
const ex5_result = has_valid_descendants(
  create_collection( ex5_ids, ex5_values ),
  ex5_search_value
);
console.log( 'expect 5: { id: 1, value: 7 }' );
console.log( `example 5: ${ JSON.stringify( ex5_result ) }` );


// example6:
// Note: I've added || 'final index'; to the has_valid_descendants() function.
const ex6_search_value = 2;
const ex6_ids = [-1, 2, -1, -1, -1];
const ex6_values = [3, 2, 1, 0, 7];
// expect "final index"
const ex6_result = has_valid_descendants(
  create_collection( ex6_ids, ex6_values ),
  ex6_search_value
);
console.log( 'expect 6: "final index"' );
console.log( `example 6: ${ JSON.stringify( ex6_result ) }` );
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being clear enough earlier m_m I've added examples with another attempt on iterating. "I want to check if any of the ids following the id corresponding with my value, is not -1 ?" It's not. I want to check if the next item in data to search having -1 or not in the value and skip if do have -1 until found != = -1 or return "final index" if the next item doesn't have any leftover id with != -1.

Comment: I don't see the difference. You want to keep checking ids until you found one that isn't -1, or 'final index' if none are, since you mentioned the need to recursively check. I've updated the shortest code a bit to return the value instead of the id or "final index", but the algo is the same. For the longer code using objects, I only had to add `|| "final index"` to make it return final index if the length is 0. Your two extra examples both work with my code, so I do think both my codes are correct.

Comment: `to make it return final index if the length is 0` should be `to make it return final index if no object is found`. And your value is inside `result.value` obviously.

Comment: Yeah. I've upvoted both answer. It's just that I can't accept two answer at the same time.